# How to get a list of views (profiles) in google analytics api v4

Tags: google-analytics-api

I'm trying to upgrade my script from using version 3 of the google analytics API to version 4.

In version 3, I could get listings of accounts, properties, and views from the api (see [API reference for version 3](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles/list)).  However, the [API reference for version 4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/) does not seem to show the same thing.

How do I get those listings now?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

TLDR: You get the view listings the same way you always have.

The [Analytics Reporting API V4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4) is a stand alone API for querying an Analytics View for data. There is not V4 management API, only the [Analytics Management API V3](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/). The two APIs are designed to be used together.

To load both the V3 and V4 libraries in Python:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build;

analytics = build('analytics', 'v3', http=http)
analyticsReporting = build('analyticsreporting','v4', http=http)
```

The best way to list all the views of a user is to call `accountsummaries.list()` -- See the [method reference docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountSummaries/list) for details.

```
account_summaries = analytics.management().accountSummaries().list().execute()
```

Parse the response to get the `viewId` of interest, and call the V4 API:

```
response = analyticsreporting.reports().batchGet(
  body={
    "reportRequests":[
    {
      "viewId": viewId,
      "dateRanges":[
        {
          "startDate":"2015-06-15",
          "endDate":"2015-06-30"
        }],
      "metrics":[
        {
          "expression":"ga:sessions"
        }],
      "dimensions": [
        {
          "name":"ga:browser"
        }]
      }]
  }
).execute()
```